# Exponare 5.6 zoom & pan no longer works in embedded browser

Tags: gis, embedded-browser

Previously our clients work on Exponare 3.5. We didn't have any issue zoom & pan in embedded browser. But after they updating to Exponare 5.6 eventhough map is working fine zoom & pan longer works. Any ideas please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manage to rectify the issue. Issue was due to embedded IE version. Exponare 6 doen't work with IE 11 properly. Client machine was using IE 11. In our installer we have change the registry to use IE 11 as well. If I change the value for my application name in following path "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION" either in "HKLM" or "HKCU" to IE 10 (see the image) it works.[image]